# Mathematisation of Peter principle?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, order-theory, mathematical-modeling

The [Peter principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle) is a management concept that describes a common observation within hierarchical organizations. It says that individuals tend to be promoted to positions of increasing responsibility based on their success in previous roles. At some point, they may reach a level where they are no longer competent. Because the skills and abilities that led to success in one position do not automatically guarantee competence in a different role.

I want to justify this sound judgment mathematically. I think we can assume the following simplified setting:

> Hierarchical organization: A countably infinite partially ordered set $S$ with the following properties.

- Every element has a unique immediate predecessor (Everyone has a manager)
- Join semi-lattice (Any two people have a common manager)
- Finite antichain condition (For any person, the number of incomparable individuals in the organization is finite)

> Promotions: A sequence of $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of bijective non-decreasing (need not to be monotone) functions on $S$

> Competency level: $\color{Red}{\text{???}}$ (I'm not sure how we can model this notion)

In the end, I suppose the Peter principle should follows from the fact that, for any $a\in S$ the set $\{a, f_1(a), f_2f_1(a), \cdots\}$ is finite.

Can somebody help me fill in the missing part of this model. Or, correct me if I am doing something nonsensical.

Comment: Sounds like a mathematical argument that would be very applicable to all the countably infinite companies out there.

Comment: This looks too complicated. Why do you have a infinite partially ordered set $S$  and a finite antichain? Why do either of these matter?

Comment: @Henry: Without the infiniteness, I do not see a way to model promotions without changing the organizational structure. Also, finite antichain is a reasonable thing to assume, but it may not be the case. Do you have any reason to believe that these assumptions are irrelevant?

Comment: The finite antichain seems irrelevant; what you may need is at least one post beyond the individual's competency level.  And I think there is a possible issue with countably infinite posts: suppose there are posts with required competency of $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ and other posts with required competency of $1+\frac{1}{2^m}$ (with $m$ and $n$ natural numbers so a countably infinite number of posts) on your individual has competency $1$; I do not see why this individual need ever be promoted to posts for which they are not competent: there is always one they can be promoted to which they can do.

Comment: @Henry: I see your point. So, what properties would you suggest for me to assume to make this model?

Comment: Is insufficient competency a filter in this semi-lattice? (I.e., is "this job is too big for person X" a filter?)

Comment: Some of the research mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle#Research_and_related_works) has models.